# Google Analytics Track Screen(UIViewController) inside Pod Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, cocoapods, mwphotobrowser

I have integrated `MWPhotoBrowser` in my app using CocaPods. I am using Google Analytics V3 and I have to track if user visit images open by `MWPhotoBrowser`. I can not import following files in Cocoa pods library file MWPhotoBrowser.m

```
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: assume that if your dependency changes what will happen , you want to track the screen of MWphotobrowser -- call the self.screenName is where u used the MWphotobrowser in the particular view controller

Comment: @Karthik I could not understand your suggestion, did you mean that I should add self.screenName where alloc init the MWPhotoBrowser.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround would probably be to subclass MWPhotoBrowser inside of your project and add the Google Analytics tracking there instead of in MWPhotoBrowser.m directly.